# Monitor, black went blue

Tags: pixel, monitor

Just all of a sudden everything thats supposed to be black turned blue on my monitor. The problem is in the monitor because when its not connected the black screen is blue. How to fix this

Comment: This is a programming Q&A. We're not here to fix your monitor.

Comment: Chances are your monitor is broken.  Try restarting it?

Comment: Flagged, this is far outside this website's scope.